# SQL query to create an index that will improve performance of the given scenario

Tags: sql, performance, indexing

**A website's internal search engine stored the following table the number of times each phrase (in lower case form) was searched for:**

TABLE searchedPhrases
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
text VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
count INTEGER NOT NULL;

Autocomplete suggestions are generated using the folllowing SQL query :

SELECT text FROM searchedPhrases
WHERE text LIKE 'input_text%'
ORDER BY count DESC;

Note: here input_text is in lower case form.

Write a SQL statement to create an index that will improve the performance of the query.

I know to create index based on specific attribute, but how to create an index that improve the performance, Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which indexing technology you have in the targeted RDBMS.

Because I think it is a school problem, and because I am also professor, I will give you some thoughts...

If B-TREE indexes are used in your DBMS (probably all DBMS uses B-TREE) the perfect index will be :

```
CREATE INDEX X ON searchedPhrases (text );
```

Comment: Thank you so much.....This makes a better understanding.